# Does the C++ compiler generate "this" pointer for all member methods, or only for those who reference members?

Tags: c++, pointers, this

Does the C++ compiler generate the hidden "this" pointer for all member methods, or only for those who reference members?

Comment: Which C++ compiler? Nonetheless, if your function doesn't access any members, why is it a member function?

Comment: @sftrabbit - I am completely new to C++ and try to figure out how are C++ features implemented in regard to C

Comment: The answer is "it depends". This is why member functions aren't directly convertible to function pointers, for example.

Comment: @Pubby - I'd appreciate if you can elaborate on the subject in an answer or point me to one. I've been reading that pointers to member methods are more than one pointer, but that's about it.

Comment: @Named - but it should be passed as a hidden parameter to signify which instance calls the method, right?

Comment: @Named: That description makes no sense. `this` cannot be thought as a member, as it is what lets you access the members. It is a *hidden* argument to non-static member functions, and yes, to *all* non-static member functions.

Comment: @Named - yes, I don't think you can access `this` outside of a member method in the class itself. So it is not stored as a class member, it is only passed hidden to non-static member functions, at least that is what common sense dictates.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Even that's not quite accurate. The hidden argument is an *object reference*. `this` is an expression whose value is a pointer to that object. The `this` comes *after* the instance argument has been passed, if you will.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The standard does not say anything about an *object reference* or *pointer* or anything else being passed, only that `this` is available inside non-member functions. Now in literature you can read (for example in 'The C++ Object Model') descriptions in terms of a pointer being passed to the function --this is **not** what the standard says, but rather what implementors do. Also note that in most (all?) implementations the low level implementation of references passed to functions is a pointer that is automatically dereferenced.

Comment: @KerrekSB: note that in the original comment I did not mention pointer or references, just that it is the means to access the object. While it is not a precise description, I don't think you can say that it is not accurate :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: It sounds like the quibble was with your description of `this` as being *passed* to the function.  I personally don't see the point of the distinction -- however it works, the function has a `this` -- but eh.  Pedantry.

Comment: @cHao: The quibble normally arises when people say that `const` member functions expect the `this` pointer to be `const`, and then it starts getting to be a bit upside down (and even worse so for `&&`-qualified member functions). But indeed it is a minor point.

Comment: Your question doesn't consider the case where the function accesses the object's own address, i.e.'this', without using any member variables or functions.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I think some of this quibbling could have been avoided if your original sentence had said 'parameter' rather than 'argument'. It's a formal parameter, but not an actual argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer: Well, if it's not using ANY member variables, why would it be a member function in the first place [and not a static member function]. (Yes, there may be cases where an interface provides a member method that isn't doing anything with any member content, since it's just doing something like printing an error message for calling this function on the wrong type, or it's a "we need this sometimes function", and in the cases when nothing needs to be done, it's an empty function).

Since we can use a member function without the compiler knowing what it actually does (for example in the case of different source files for the "use" and "definition" of the function), the compiler MUST follow the same calling convention for all calls, whether the `this` pointer is actually needed or not. It's of course possible that if the code if visible to the compiler that it inlines the function or otherwise can make optimizations that produce better code under circumstances that allow this. But the "default" if the compiler doesn't know any better is to pass `this` along to the function, whether it is actually needed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the C++ Standard (Draft N3242):

> ### 9.3.2 The this pointer
>
> 1 In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword this is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called.

I think this means that it is present in all member functions.

Comment: He's asking how the implementation compiles it, which can't be answered by the standard.

Comment: I think if the standard says that there is a this pointer for each member function, a compiler that is conformant to the standard cannot omit it in the first place. Since you could even want to access the object address in this without referencing any members. (That doesn't mean that the compiler may not optimize it away if it isn't accessed at all, accoding to "as-if"... But what type of optimization a compiler applies is very specific to the compiler.)

Comment: @Pixelchemist It can omit it under the *as-if* rule. If the function doesn't use `this` then whether it is there or not doesn't affect the execution of the program.

Comment: @Pubby Additionally he didn't specify a compiler so the answer was to be provided based on what is common to all C++ compilers: _The standard_.

Answer (score 0):

"The C++ compiler" might act quite differently, depending on who he is at the exact point in space and time.

That said, the way most compilers implement classes and objects, `this` is part of every instance of a class. This means, it is accessible in the complete scope of the object.

Comment: I am more concerned with the actual method parameters. In C, I manually pass the instance pointer as a `self` pointer, I am curious if C++ compilers do the same and if automatically for every member method.

Comment: Given the requirement to support separate translation units, the compiler has no choice but to pass 'this' for every member function. The second paragraph is completely confused. The question is *about* C++ compilers, which *must* 'implement classes and objects'. 'this' is not 'part of every instance of a class', it is a value passed in from outside. Objects don't really have scopes.

Comment: @EJP 1. The second paragraph talks about *the way most compilers implement classes and objects*, which IMHO already implies **that** they do so. 2. `this` is definitly a part of an instance: It is a reference to it.

Comment: A reference to an instance is not part of an instance. The members are parts of the instance. The reference has to come from outside, otherwise it is inaccessible, because you still need a reference to get to the internal reference, so you don't need the internal reference.

Comment: OK. I am not willing to discuss, that a reference to something is not a property of that thing. Be invited to downvote.

Comment: You're changing your terminology. There's a difference between being a 'part' of something, which implies membership, and an 'attribute' or 'property' of something, which doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Every object in C++ has access to its own address through a pointer called this pointer. The `this` pointer is an implicit parameter to all member functions.Where as friend functions do not have a `this` pointer. Only member functions have `this` pointer.

Comment: `friend` is a red herring. Functions are not "members or friends". Functions are "members" or "non-members" and `friend`ship is largely orthogonal to the property of membership.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Interval
{
    public:
       long GetTime()
       {
           //Code
       }

       void SetTime(long value)
       {
           //Code
       }
}
```

Suppose you have written this code. Compiler will add the this pointer automatically. And it will appear to you when you view the compiler written code for your program.

Compiler will add as follows:

```
void Interval::SetTime(Interval* this, long value)
```