# Confusing Private variable access

Tags: c++, private

Can private variable of one instance be available in the function of other instance.

The following code is printing 5

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        A(int value) {
            x = value;
        }
        void printValue(A *obj) {
            std::cout << obj->x;
        }

    private:
        int x;
};

void main()
{
    A obj1(3);
    A obj2(5);

    obj1.printValue(&obj2);
    getchar();
    return;
}
```

Can anyone please explain why this happens. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can. `private:` and `protected:` restrictions are per class, not per instance. What matters is where the code doing the access is located. If the code accessing something `private` is located in the same class, or in a `friend class`, or a `friend` function, then access is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Scope of being `private` applies to anything inside that type, not any only `this` instance.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfbte35d.aspx): "When preceding a list of class members, the private keyword specifies that those members are accessible only from member functions and friends of the class."

Answer (score 1):

Let's modify `printValue`:

```
void printValue() 
{
    A *obj = this;
    std::cout << obj->x;
}
```

If you say this shouldn't get compiled because by `obj` we are trying to access element of other object. If that holds true, no class can even be made to access element of its own. Copy/Move constructors, (move) assignment operators won't work.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is not only logical, but also very useful. Consider

```
class Point2D {
  public:
    Point2D (int x, int y) : x(x), y(y);
    Point2D& operator+=(const Point2D& other) {
      x += other.x;
      y += other.y;
      return *this;
    }
  private:
    int x, y;
}
```

If you could not access `other`'s private members in `operator+=`, you'd be forced to make public getters and setters and the whole point of having `x` and `y` private would be arguably lost. Hence `private` hides the members form the outside world, but not from instances of the same class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes both Obj1 and Obj2 are of class A. So the member function certainly can access anything inside the object. To get more understanding, you should try to understand how a member function actually operates on an object through which it is called.

Let us take your example and adding one more function printValue() to it to explain more:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        A(int value) {
            x = value;
        }
        void printValue(A *obj) {
            std::cout << obj->x;
        }
        void printValue() {             // who supplies 'this' pointer accessible inside the function
            std::cout<< this->x;
        }

    private:
        int x;
};

void main()
{
    A obj1(3);
    A obj2(5);

    obj1.printValue(&obj2);
    getchar();
    return;
}
```

note that I have added a member function void printValue(); and it uses this->x, which is [provided by the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636563/does-the-c-compiler-generate-this-pointer-for-all-member-methods-or-only-fo) and the function call for

`obj1.printValue(&obj2)` is translated by compiler to `printvalue(this, &obj2)`.
That is why when you call `obj1.printValue()` that i have added, it will be called like
`printValue(this)` where `this = &obj1` provided by the compiler.

so effectively a member function always access an object using its pointer. In your case, there are 2 objects: 1 that you provide and one that is supplied by the compiler.

I hope this explains your doubt.